# turtle graphics Turtle slows down

Tags: python, performance, turtle-graphics

I set the turtle to fastest and when I ran the first loop alone it was fine but as I added more it became comparably to when it was just executing first loop alone. I don't know if this is just because of the complexity of the drawing but it takes a decently long amount of time to complete the shape. Is there anthing I can do to fix this?

```
import turtle

turtle.bgcolor("Red")
turtle.color("Yellow", "Pink")
turtle.shape("turtle")
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.speed("fastest")

while True:
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.left(179)
    turtle.circle(20)
    if abs(turtle.pos()) < 1:
        break

turtle.setheading(270)



while True:
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.left(179)
    turtle.circle(20)
    if abs(turtle.pos()) < 1:
        break

turtle.setheading(180)


while True:
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.left(179)
    turtle.circle(20)
    if abs(turtle.pos()) < 1:
        break

turtle.setheading(90)


while True:
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.left(179)
    turtle.circle(20)
    if abs(turtle.pos()) < 1:
        break


turtle.end_fill()



turtle.getscreen()._root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What was fast and what was not fast? I can't figure it out from the question.

Comment: Note that turtle is not a drawing library. It is an educational tool. Not meant to be fast.

Comment: When I run your code I don't really notice it slowing down. Regardless, I suggest that you add a call to `turtle.hideturtle()` right after the `turtle.speed("fastest")` call you already have because, as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.hideturtle) says, "...hiding the turtle speeds up the drawing observably".

Answer (score 1):

My analysis is that your filling, i.e. `turtle.begin_fill()` and `turtle.end_fill()`, is slowing down the code 3X to no real effect.  One of these images is *with* fill, one is *without*:

[image]

If you can't appreciate the difference (even at full size) then the fill is probably just a waste of time.  If you just want the final image, and don't care about watching it being drawn, then for more performance, I suggest something like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("Red")
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.color("Yellow", "Pink")

for heading in range(0, 360, 90):

    turtle.setheading(heading)

    turtle.begin_fill()

    while True:
        turtle.forward(300)
        turtle.left(179)
        turtle.circle(20)
        if abs(turtle.pos()) < 1:
            break

    turtle.end_fill()

screen.tracer(True)
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks ! Didn't realise it was the animation that was slowing it down so much